# Make box in math mode with current math font

Tags: fonts, math-mode, boxes

The commands

```
$\mathcal{\mbox{$M$}}$
```

and

```
\mbox{$\mathcal{M}$}
```

produce different output.  I would like a replacement for `\mbox` that creates a box preserving all features of the current font in math mode.  How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you give us a good use case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please always post complete documents:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
$\mathcal{\count0=\fam\mbox{$\fam=\count0 M$}}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: That works perfectly; thank you.  I'll post complete documents in the future.

Comment: @JonathanWise why do you want this by the way? hard to think of any time it would be useful compared to just using `\mathcal{M}`

Comment: I am trying to make a version of \overline and \underline that looks right on slanted characters.

Comment: @JonathanWise Have you seen: [What does “XY Problem” mean?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-does-xy-problem-mean)

Comment: I discovered today that \count0 also stores the page number, so I used \count@ instead.

Comment: @JonathanWise it does, but it doesn't matter as that is a local setting, it can not interfere with the page number as used, unless you want to print the page number inside the `\mathcal`

Answer (score 6):

You can use the similar commands `\mathmbox` or `\mathmakebox` provided by the [`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package.

Comment: If I have understood the OP correctly, he wants to have `\mathcal{M}` as result, but `\mathcal{\mathmbox{M}}` gives the other M.